# Does copying speed depend on or vary with file-types?

Tags: performance, file-transfer

I want to know does file-copy speed depend-on/vary-with file-types? For **same size** file but difference in type of file (Ex: exe, dll, zip, ppt etc.).

If It depends then Why/How?

Answer (score 3):

Copy speed on modern operating systems usually doesn't depend on the file's type, since files are usually copied as chunks of bytes.

What matters more is the file system that the file lives on (NTFS, FAT32, ext3, etc), the read/write speed of the medium (SSD, hard drives, DVDs), and the channel it's going through (Ethernet, WiFi, system bus, etc).

Fragmented files also take longer to copy on mediums like hard drives, since the drive head needs to move around more to read the data.

Comment: I would add that if you have antivirus installed, this may cause certain types to be slower because it will try to scan them on access and write.